# Changing String type date to Day string

Tags: java, android, datetime

I'm using an API for my weather app and the JSON this API returns, gives me the 'Date' like that:`"date": "2016-08-20"` which is string type. But I want to write the day on screen like 'wednesday'. I look up for conversion on the internet but I couldn't find the solution for my case. Can anyone explain how to do that. Thanks in advance. By the way this is an android project.

Comment: there is no conversion what you need to search, search instead for **"Parsing"**

Comment: Okey I look for that

Comment: I guess that is what you need....https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need 2 `SimpleDateFormat`ters,

1. one to parse the `String` value of current date and get `Date`
   object from it.
2. and second to get the week in `String` value from that `Date` Object.

**Output**

```
Saturday
```

**Code**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2016-08-20");
        String dayOfWeek = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE").format(date);
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
    }
}
```

**OR - One Line Code** - *If we ignore Readability*

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2016-08-20")));
    }
}
```

Comment: @AhmetUrun Glad that it worked. Please see the edited answer as well. I've optimized it by not using extra `Calendar` object.

Answer (score 1):

You may use split to tokenize the string but I prefer using DateFormat because it's a standard way to do the process :

```
String dateString ="2016-08-20";
SimpleDateFormat formatInput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = formatInput.parse(dateString);
SimpleDateFormat formatOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
String  day = formatOutput.format(date);
```

The idea is creating a `Date` instance from the date in string `2016-08-20` and then from the `Date` instance formatting it to render the day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

this might help,

```
String weekDay = "";
     DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(df.parse(yourDateAsStringHere));
         int dayOfWeek= cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

            if (Calendar.MONDAY == dayOfWeek) {
                weekDay = "monday";
            } else if (Calendar.TUESDAY == dayOfWeek) {
                weekDay = "tuesday";
            } else if (Calendar.WEDNESDAY == dayOfWeek) {
                weekDay = "wednesday";
            } else if (Calendar.THURSDAY == dayOfWeek) {
                weekDay = "thursday";
            } else if (Calendar.FRIDAY == dayOfWeek) {
                weekDay = "friday";
            } else if (Calendar.SATURDAY == dayOfWeek) {
                weekDay = "saturday";
            } else if (Calendar.SUNDAY == dayOfWeek) {
                weekDay = "sunday";
            }
```

Comment: That doesn't compile and it's a very long way to write `new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2016-08-20"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` class, for example:

```
try {
            String inputStr = "2016-08-20";
            Date inputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(inputStr);
            String dayName = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(inputDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```